# Why Projector Keep Re-syncing?

Tags: audio, projector

I bought an HDMI booster to help my 5 meter HDMI to get signal boost without any Audio or Video Dropout. I joined two different HDMI cable to use it on my projector but my projector keep re syncing every 2 sec when i'm using the booster for strong signal, Any idea why I'm having this re sync issue?

Comment: perhaps the signal is too strong. 15 meters is generally the maximum cable length for HDMI. I don't think you should need a booster for 5 meters. Perhaps a cable is damaged/defective.

Comment: also, is the booster next to the projector or next to the source?

Comment: @Jon   HDMi looses audio randomly without the booster tho so, i'm not sure what is wrong for sure. the booster is next to the projector. Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: I'd try the booster next to the signal source

Comment: @Jon I've try tired that and the Projector went through "searching HDMI source" twice already. Do i have to get rid of the booster , any other suggestion??

Comment: Try a new cable